# Why was Quaid so sure about starting the reactor (Total Recall)?

Tags: mars, plot-device, total-recall

In *Total Recall*, Quaid, after meeting Kuato, seems to be certain that starting the reactor was a good idea

This idea seems to have been given to him by Kuato (his final words were to start the reactor and free Mars) and even Kuato seems to have found out about the reactor being present only after unlocking Quaid/Hauser's memory)

But as Cohaagen says in Quaid's repressed memory, they had no idea what the reactor was supposed to do, or if it was even still operational

Even during the last fight just before Quaid throws him out into the Martian environment, Cohaagen keeps pleading with Quaid to not start the reactor, which he seemed to be sure would melt the planet

**Then how was Quaid so sure that starting the reactor would be a good idea, that it would create an atmosphere for Mars, instead of causing a planetary meltdown?**

Comment: Is this the 2012 or the 1990 movie?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The 2012 movie does not take place on mars...

Comment: @Tritium21 the 2012 version doesn't exist in my reality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Because it was better than an alternative

Yes, there was a risk that it would melt the planet, but Quaid heart was with the resistance and the resistance wanted to turn on the reactor. If the reactor would create the atmosphere resistance would win and grip on poor people would be lost. If Quaid wouldn't turn it on - thousands of people would suffocate and rest would live practically in a slavery. Also he did it,  because it was exactly what Cohaagen didn't want him to do, and Quaid had a quite few reasons to hate him (and frankly his arguments were quite weak). I so its a bit of "I'll do it just because my enemy doesn't want me to do" and  "better die standing than live on your knees" philosophy.

or...

> Its is just a part of his pre-programmed memory, where at the end he was supposed to save the planet, so he was just following the scenario.